# Django ModelForm: How to display user specific data in a drop-down field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a drop-down field called **Label** as part of a model called **Birthday**. My problem is that the drop-down field shows the Labels from all users. How can I make sure it only shows the Labels specific to the User?

I assume that a query is required in the form model but I have no clue how to do this.

## forms

```
class BirthdayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Birthday
        fields = ('name', 'day', 'label')

class LabelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ('tag',)
```

## models

```
class Label(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Birthday(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    day = models.DateField()
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=0, null=True, blank=True) 
    
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name
```

## view

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BirthdayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            birthday = form.save(commit=False)
            birthday.user = request.user
            birthday.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = BirthdayForm()
    birthday = Birthday.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    username = request.user
    return render(request, 'bd_calendar/index.html', {'form': form, 'birthday': birthday, 'username': username })
```

## template

```
            <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                <table border="0">
                    {{ form }}
                </table>
                <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
class BirthdayForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Birthday
        fields = ('name', 'day', 'label')
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BirthdayForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['label'].queryset = Label.objects.filter(user=user)
```

hope it helps

Comment: I get this error: TypeError at /

__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'